# Что обозначает знак "#" в данном выражении?

Tags: python, syntax

В Python 3.6 вы можете использовать f-строки, чтобы сделать этот чист:

```
rgb = (0,128, 64)
f'#{rgb[0]:02x}{rgb[1]:02x}{rgb[2]:02x}'
```

Comment: Это просто символ, который как есть попадает в строку.

Comment: Это значит, что в строку у вас подставляются значения из списка rgb в шестнадцатиричной нотации, и в итоге вы получаете принятое в html обозначение цвета '#008040'. То есть, сам это символ означает только себя и ничего больше.

Comment: `print( '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]) )`

Comment: А :02x - это сам конвертер в 16иричный код?